# Conversion to date time from char string failed on Insert but works on Update

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

i'm currently getting the following error when inserting a date into a database, but it works fine when amending the date via a update:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

The code I have (Very crappy i know, learning on the fly...):

**update - working**

```
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("Update bookings set Guests = '" + 
    drptxtGuests.Text + "'," + "CheckInDate = '" + 
    BasicDatePicker1.SelectedDate + "'," + "CheckOutDate = '" + 
    BasicDatePicker2.SelectedDate + "',"  + "RoomType = '" + 
    drptxtRoomType.Text + "'," + "Price = '" + txtBookingPrice.Text + 
    "' where BookingNumber = '" + txtBookingNumber.Text + "'"  , con);

update.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

**insert - error**

```
SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("Insert into bookings(BookingNumber, MemberID, " +
    "CheckInDate, CheckOutDate, Guests, RoomType, Price) values('" +
    txtBookingNumber.Text + "','" + Session["id"] + "','" + 
    BasicDatePicker1.SelectedDate + "','" + BasicDatePicker2.SelectedDate + 
    "','" + drptxtGuests.Text + "','" + drptxtRoomType.Text + "','" + 
    txtBookingPrice.Text + "')", con);

insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

i wouldn't be surprised if it was something very basic, obvious and stupid but please bear with me. :)

edit: Im also certain that the problem is with the datepickers, i just dont understand why it works for updating and not inserting?

Comment: Learn to use proper parameters instead of munging query strings with user input.

Comment: immediately helpful..

Comment: can you paste the SqlCommand query strings constructed for both the cases after they have been instantiated.

Comment: What makes you certain it has to do with the `DatePicker` controls? Try setting a breakpoint on the line: `insert.ExecuteNonQuery();` and examine the value of `insert`.